How to setup multi-host cni communication between containers on hashicorp nomad clusters
So i recently create a nomad cluster with consul as kv store and dns with three nodes to deploy jobs/containers. But i'm unable to use anything that allow communication between containers on diffrent hosts of same clusters and only access ip of containers that on same host

i use bridge that only works inside same host (as it should be)
i use cilium cni using netreap and it didn't work too this dose give
each container diffrent ip but can't communication among containers
of sparate hosts
(https://cosmonic.com/blog/engineering/netreap-a-practical-guide-to-running-cilium-in-nomad)

weave net is not working as weave launch failed due to docker client api version error
Expected behaviour: can have diffrent ip of each container that deployed via nomad jobs and can communicate using ip of that container on from sparate host (both via ping and with any other command like curl nc etcs)
But nothing works Can anyone help me . I suffered on this so much that i don't want anyone to go through that
